# Trouble pickling and unpickling on OSX "non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling"

Tags: python, macos, class, pickle

I am trying to pickle and unpickle an instance of a data class that I am working with and it works all okay on Unix:

```
import dataclass as dc

data = dc.DataClass()
f = open(filename, 'wb')
pickle.dump(data, f)
f.close()

f = open(filename, 'rb')
unpickled_data = pickle.load(f)
```

So I can then work again with `unpicked_data`. However when I try these same steps on mac OS X I get an error:

```
f = open(filename, 'rb')
unpickled_data = pickle.load(f)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

pickle.pyc in load(file)
   1376 
   1377 def load(file):
-> 1378     return Unpickler(file).load()
   1379 
   1380 def loads(str):

pickle.pyc in load(self)
    856             while 1:
    857                 key = read(1)
--> 858                 dispatch[key](self)
    859         except _Stop, stopinst:
    860             return stopinst.value

pickle.pyc in load_build(self)
   1215         setstate = getattr(inst, "__setstate__", None)
   1216         if setstate:
-> 1217             setstate(state)
   1218             return
   1219         slotstate = None

ValueError: non-string names in Numpy dtype unpickling
```

I have tried pickling and unpickling simpler objects such as dictionaries on OS X and it seems to work fine. But for some reason is not liking this data class. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Are you pickling in python 3 and unpickling in python 2? I am facing the same problem

Comment: I am having the exact same problem. Did you manage to get this working?